# jQuery plugin with methods and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, methods

I'm working on a kind of do-it-all basic framework for jQuery plugins. I'm basing the structure off of the jQuery Plugins/Authoring example found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Here's a further simplified version of the structure I'm building:

```
(function( $ ){
  var methods = {
     init : function( options ) { 
        var defaults = {
            // place default settings for plugin here
        }

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('PLUGINNAME'); 

            if ( ! data ) { 
             // do more setup stuff here
            }
        });
     },

     destroy : function( ) { 
       return this.each(function(){ 
        // do stuff to destroy any function binding
       })
     },

     update : function( content ) { 
        return this.each(function() { 
            //do your update stuff here
        })
     }
  };

  $.fn.PLUGINNAME = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) { 
      return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 )); 
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) { 
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments ); 
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.PLUGINNAME' ); 
    }    
  };
})( jQuery );
```

The piece that I'm trying to figure out now is how to add a callback function to the plugin call. I know that I'll need another parameter like this:

```
  $.fn.PLUGINNAME = function( method, callback ) {
```

but I'm not sure how to go about implementing that based on what I currently have.

Comment: what is this callback supposed to do and what is its signature?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the callback is supposed to do. Maybe it's just a function that needs to wait until the plugin runs some script (like a getJSON call) before it can process some element on the page.

Answer (score 1):

To call the callback function, you can use the .call method.

```
init : function( options, callback ) { 
    callback.call(this, options);
```

In the example, I passed in options, but you can pass in whatever you need to.

Comment: But, how does that work with the idea of chainability of the plugin that using the `return this.each(function(){ ` return allows?

Comment: The callback won't effect "this" so as long as you return "this" it will remain chainable.
You can look at some of the jQuery default functions that allow callback to see what parameters they pass in.

Comment: So would my update method look something like this then? `update : function( options, callback ) { 
        return this.each(function() { 
            callback.call(this, options);
        })
     }` And is there any change to the plugin itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be working with my current structure. I'll have to revisit this later.